# Can a AES 256 key be recovered with the encrypted and decrypted message?

Tags: cryptography, aes

I have no advanced knowledge in cryptography.

Is it possible to recover the AES-256 key with the decrypted and encrypted message?

Comment: I think you're talking about either a chosen plaintext or known plaintext attack. See [Security of AES against known plaintext attack if no IV is used?](/q/138229) and [Is symmetric encryption vulnerable to known plaintext attack?](/q/16165)

Comment: See https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1512/why-is-aes-resistant-to-known-plaintext-attacks

Comment: Another link: [Can I recover a lost AES key?](/q/199879)